# Implement custom Arithmetic System

Tags: java, math, hex, integer-arithmetic

I need to implement a custom integer arithmetic system, like Hexadecimal but with 4 more letters.

For example, Hexadecimal uses `[0-9,A-F]` to represent a number. Mine will use `[0-9,A-J]`.

```
Sample representations:  
Decimal(5): Hex(5), MySystem(5)
Decimal(15): Hex(F), MySystem(F)
Decimal(16): Hex(10), MySystem(G)
Decimal(17): Hex(11), MySystem(H)
Decimal(18): Hex(12), MySystem(I)
Decimal(19): Hex(13), MySystem(J)
Decimal(20): Hex(14), MySystem(10)
...
```

I cannot decide if i should store numbers as `String` or as `BigInteger`.
It would really help if you could point me to somewhere where i could read how Hex is implemented in code. So far, i have only been able to find implementations only for conversions from/to other arithmetic systems.

Comment: you can start from Integer.parseInt(s, radix) source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just integers with a radix of 20 (base 20).

Remember the difference between the *value* (an abstract concept) and its *representation*.  You care about representation only on input and output.  When you input values they will be represented in base-20, and you want to output them in base-20.  As long as that interface is satisfied, how the numbers are represented inside your code shouldn't matter, so you should use the most convenient representation for the range you need to cover (int, long or BigInteger).

Java already has all the necessary infrastructure to deal with this. Check out the `Integer.parseInt(String value, int radix)` for input.  For output there's `Integer.toString(int value, int radix)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you could show me where to find some code of Hex implementation, that would be great!

Comment: @g7k Why? You've just been told you don't need it.

Comment: @EJP I have accepted the answer, i know now that i don't need it and that's how i will implement it. But i would still love to read how Hex is implemented if that's ok :-)

Comment: note that MAX_RADIS constant is 36 which is ok for system 0-z but not OK if you want to have system with more symbols.